Can the luminous intensity on an optical target exceed that of multiple individual sources pointing to it?
I know that the brightness of an image cannot be brighter than the source (intensity at an optical target can't exceed the intensity of the source) but I wonder what would happen with two sources.
The maximal theoretical intensity achievable by concentrating sunlight on Earth is the intensity of the sun's surface. This is achieved by concentrating sunlight with the maximal concentration factor of ~46000.
What would happen if, hypothetically, there were identical 2 suns orbiting Earth close to each other at the same distance from Earth and that their respective beams were combined (on Earth) into a same beam and then concentrated with the maximal concentration factor ? Would the intensity on the target be twice the intensity of the sun's surface ?

yes, and if you split the sun into a million parts and only keep one, your power will be reduced by that factor. But the title does not match teh question, it cannot be larger than the sum of teh individual sources.
